# Move a file from a directory with one file to another (refactoring)

Tags: git, refactoring, git-rm, git-mv

I have a directory with a single file `Foo.java` defining a class under package `com.a.b.c` under a specific package i.e. `src/com/a/b/c/Foo.java`
I want to refactor and move the class in a different package e.g. `com.x.y.x` i.e. `src/com/x/y/z/Foo.java`
I did the refactor **from inside the IDE** I am using and that led to the `git status` showing:

```
src/com/a/b/c/Foo.java -> src/com/a/b/c/Foo.java
```

Now the issue is that the `src/com/a/b/c` is still there and empty.
I know that `git` has an issue with empty directories so now I am not sure how should I remove that? Should I do `git rm -r src/com/a/b/c` and commit everything at once? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git does not track directories, it tracks files. If you have moved everything away from `src/com/a/b/c`, you can just remove that directory from your working tree in any way you want, i.e. `rmdir src/com/a/b/c` - it has no effect on git whatsoever.

Comment: `ls` shows that `src/com/a/b/c` is there. `git rm src/com/a/b/c` outputs `fatal: pathspec 'src/com/a/b/c' did not match any files`. So basically it does not exist for `git` and I can just remove it using any OS command right?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.